# how can i know the version of phpmyadmin?

Tags: websecurity

I'm writing a program that parses the phpmyadmin version of a site, but finding out the version turned out to be much more difficult than I thought. Tell me what are the ways to find out the version? Wappalyzer is not an option

some versions are visible in the phpmyadmin login panel and some are not. There is also an option to 'hide version' which makes things even more difficult.